# What is the fastest way of changing Dictionary<K,V>?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

This is an algorithmic question.

I have got `Dictionary<object,Queue<object>>`. Each queue contains one or more elements in it. I want to remove all queues with only one element from the dictionary. What is the fastest way to do it?

Pseudo-code: `foreach(item in dict) if(item.Length==1) dict.Remove(item);`

It is easy to do it in a loop (not foreach, of course), but I'd like to know which approach is the fastest one here.

Why I want it: I use that dictionary to find duplicate elements in a large set of objects. The Key in dictionary is kind of a hash of the object, the Value is a queue of all objects found with the same hash. Since I want only duplicates, I need to remove all items with just a single object in associated queue.

**Update:**

It may be important to know that in a regular case there are just a few duplicates in a large set of objects. Let's assume 1% or less. So possibly it could be faster to leave the Dictionary as is and create a new one from scatch with just selected elements from the first one... and then deelte the first Dictionary completely. I think it depends on the comlpexity of computational Dictionary class's methods used in particular algorithms.

I really want to see this problem on a theoretical level because as a teacher I want to discuss it with students. I didn't provide any concrete solution myself because I think it is really easy to do it. The question is which approach is the best, the fastest.

Comment: Honestly, it feels like some premature optimization... How many objects are you dealing with and are you sure you need to make it quicker? What sort of times are you experiencing within a normal loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stead of trying to optimize the traversing of the collection how about optimizing the content of the collection so that it only includes the duplicates? This would require changing your collection algorithm instead to something like this

```
var duplicates = new Dictionary<object,Queue<object>>;
var possibleDuplicates = new Dictionary<object,object>();
foreach(var item in original){
    if(possibleDuplicates.ContainsKey(item)){
       duplicates.Add(item, new Queue<object>{possibleDuplicates[item],item});
       possibleDuplicates.Remove(item);
    } else if(duplicates.ContainsKey(item)){
       duplicates[item].Add(item);
    } else {
       possibleDuplicates.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no clear evidence that this answer provides the best possible solution, but I think it is the best one of solutions provided here in answers. That's why I accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

```
var itemsWithOneEntry = dict.Where(x => x.Value.Count == 1)
                            .Select(x => x.Key)
                            .ToList();

foreach (var item in itemsWithOneEntry) {
    dict.Remove(item));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't remove them form the dictionary

Comment: @Diego, "That doesn't remove then from the dictionary" - why do you say that?  Looks to me like it calls `dict.Remove` for each key selected by the `Where` clause.

Comment: @Diego, OK that explains the comment.  Funny, it doesn't show up as having been edited here.

Comment: @Joe Yes.. I think when its edited within 1 minute (or so) of creation it doesn't show.

Comment: `ForEach` is not defined for `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @Diego, OK but as it stands it's correct (though AFAIK there is no extension method `IEnumerable<T>.ForEach` - so the first line would need to have `.ToList()` unless there is a custom `ForEach` extension method somewhere).  +1 as this is probably the fastest and most succinct approach.

Comment: @Diego: You were quicker with your initial comment than me finishing the answer. @Joe and @L.B.: You can simply replace the call to `ForEach` with a foreach loop. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DennisTraub Now you are modifying the dictionary while enumerating. You should copy the keys to another list first.

Comment: @DennisTraub `.Select(x => x.Key)` doesn't change anything. As my previous comment, you should copy the keys to a list or an array

Comment: My question was: *Which approach is the fastest?* Please provide proof or at least exaplantion why do you think this one is the fastest.

Comment: @AlKepp sorry, I didn't give that part of your question the attention it deserved. I wasn't aware that you're really looking for theoretical background. I don't know if my solution is much faster or slower than others.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should probably measure the impact of this on the performance in a realistic scenario before you bother to make your code any more complex than it really needs to be. Most imagined performance problems are not in fact the real cause of slow code.

But supposing you do find that you could get a speed advantage by avoiding a linear search for queues of length 1, you could solve this problem with a technique called *indexing*.

As well as your dictionary containing all the queues, you maintain an index container (probably another dictionary) that only contains the queues of length 1, so when you need them they are already available separately.

To do this, you need to enhance all the operations that modify the length of the queue, so that they have the side-effect of updating the index container.

One way to do it is to define a class `ObservableQueue`. This would be a thin wrapper around `Queue` except it also has a `ContentsChanged` event that fires when the number of items in the queue changes. Use `ObservableQueue` everywhere instead of the plain `Queue`.

Then when you create a new queue, enlist on its `ContentsChanged` event a handler that checks to see if the queue only has one item. Based on this you can either insert or remove it from the index container.